# Linking SQL Server 2012 32 bit and Ubuntu MySQL 64 bit

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Can I add a Ubuntu based 64 bit MySQL server as a linked server to a 32 bit SQL Server 2012 ? What do I need to do the same ?

Do I need to install the MySQL ODBC drivers on both Ubuntu and Windows or only Windows ?